# In Python, urllib.urlretrieve downloads a file which says "Go away"

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to download the (APK) files from links such as https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=215041. When you enter the link in your browser, it brings up a dialog to open or save the file (see below).

[image]

I would like to save the file using a Python script. I've tried the following:

```
import urllib

download_link = 'https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=215041'
download_file = '/tmp/apkmirror_test/youtube.apk'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urllib.urlretrieve(url=download_link, filename=download_file)
```

but the resulting `youtube.apk` contains only the words "Go away".

Since I am able to download the file by pasting the link in my browser's address bar, there must be some difference between that and `urllib.urlretrieve` that makes this not work. Can someone explain this difference and how to eliminate it?

Comment: The server could be looking at the user agent, noticing that you're trying to download the file using code instead of a regular browser, and serving you a different file. You can customize the user agent by adding the correct header, thereby *spoofing* a regular browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not programmatically access that download page as it is disallowed in the robots.txt:
https://www.apkmirror.com/robots.txt

That being said, your request header is different. Python by default sets User-Agent to something like "Python...". That is the most likely cause of detection.